# Keeping an object in memory if two other objects hold references

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have three objects: a Query, a Document, and an Index. A Query uses an Index to speed up access to a Document. An Index is specific to a (Query, Document) pair; a Query may have multiple indexes for different Documents, and a Document may have multiple Indexes for different Queries. A Query may outlive a Document (because it can still be used to search other Documents) and a Document may outlive a Query (because it can still be accessed by other Queries). I want the Index to stay in memory so long as both the Query and the Document are still around, and I want it to be garbage-collected when either the Query or the Document disappear. The Index can be rebuilt if necessary, but I would prefer to avoid this.

Currently I'm using WeakReferences from the Query to the Index and from the Document to the Index, but the Index is being garbage collected prematurely. When this happens the index is rebuilt so the application functions correctly, but there's an overhead.

Any suggestions on how to organize this? I realise I could switch to using a SoftReference to make garbage collection of the Index less likely, but I actually want to encourage garbage collection when either the Query or the Document disappears.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about caching strategies. My advise would be to find an existing open source caching software and tweak it to your needs or otherwise contribute with the project

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about caching algorithms

Comment: The problem is similar to caching but not identical. If you can recommend a library that fits my requirements I'll be happy to consider your suggestions, but just telling me to go and look around is useless advice. Please don't try to close questions simply because you don't know the answer or don't understand the question.

Comment: I understand your question. It is not a bad question however in my opinion it doesn't meet the criteria for questions on SO. Others may differ

Comment: Sounds like you want either, `Document` to have a `WeakHashMap<Query,Index>` or `Query` having a `WeakHashMap<Document,Index>`.